# Reformatting a stopwatch .csv in Python

Tags: python, csv, formatting, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

I know that there must be a few ways of doing this, but I'd love to get your opinion on which would be the best way to do so.

I have a .csv, outputted from a phone's stopwatch application that looks like this:

```
No.,Split time,,
1,+03:16.110,,
2,+12:23.120,,
3,+15:36.187,,
4,+16:56.487,,
5,+19:30.488,,
6,+20:01.621,,
 [...]
37,+53:01.921,,
38,+53:39.738,,
39,+53:40.241,,
40,+01:06.849,,
41,+01:16.442,,
```

I need to change the stopwatch timecode into a hours:minutes:seconds:frames format, remove the column headings, add extra information and take into consideration the hour roll-over (row 40 onwards).

The output would therefore look like this:

```
cut_v01 00:03:16:00 V4  black                  
cut_v01 00:12:23:00 V4  black                  
cut_v01 00:15:36:00 V4  black                  
cut_v01 00:16:56:00 V4  black                  
cut_v01 00:19:30:00 V4  black                  
cut_v01 00:20:01:00 V4  black                  
 [...]         
cut_v01 00:53:01:00 V4  black                  
cut_v01 00:53:39:00 V4  black                  
cut_v01 00:53:40:00 V4  black                  
cut_v01 01:01:06:00 V4  black                  
cut_v01 01:01:16:00 V4  black
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Start by trying something. Anything.

Comment: The csv and datetime modules are a good place to start.

Comment: Or just `str.split` for that matter ...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out -

```
import string, sys, os

def convert_stopwatch(in_filename): 
   new_filename=in_filename.replace("Stopwatch", "Timecode")

   SW_lines=open(in_filename,'Ur').readlines() 
   timecode=open(new_filename, 'w') 

   previous_minutes = 0  
   hours = 0

   for SW_line in SW_lines:
            plus_pos = SW_line.find("+")      
            if plus_pos > -1: 
                dot_pos = SW_line.find(".")
                SW_time = SW_line[plus_pos + 1:dot_pos] 

                minutes = int(SW_time.split(":")[0]) 
                if minutes < previous_minutes: 
                    hours = hours + 1
                previous_minutes = minutes

                timecode.write("cut_v01 %02d:%s:00 V4 black\n" % (hours,SW_time) ) 

   print "Timecode file(s) successfully created:\n %s\n\n" % (new_filename) 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()): 
SW_file=""
for filename in files:
   if (filename.startswith("Stopwatch")): 
      if (filename.endswith(".csv")): 
         convert_stopwatch(os.path.join(root, filename))
```